# UNIX rename command, trying to rename some bulk files in a folder

Tags: rename

trying to rename some bulk files in a folder

mv ~/folder/subfolder/filename.rpt ~/folder/subfolder/filename_sunset.rpt

is there any command, to do this to all together?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a bash loop like the following

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*.rpt
do
    mv "$file" ./NewFileName
done
```

Comment: a) [Do not parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), b) [quote your variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/70524).